# change displaying image of current button and change other to default

Tags: jquery, html

i have a few buttons:

```
<button class="image1-button"><img src="images/button_unselected.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button"><img src="images/button_unselected.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button"><img src="images/button_unselected.png"></button>
<button class="image1-button"><img src="images/button_unselected.png"></button>
```

when i press one of them the following happen:

```
$(".image1-button").click(function(){
$(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/button_selected.png");
});
```

how can i say that the other, means not(this) get the src "images/button_unselected" that always only the currently pressed button has "button_selected"

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(".image1-button").click(function(){
    //Reset all
    $(".image1-button").find("img").attr("src", "images/button_unselected.png");
    //mark current
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/button_selected.png");
});
```

Comment: The clicked button image is changed twice, you can fix it by adding `.not(this)` to the first line. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(".image1-button").click(function(){
  $(this).find("img").attr("src", "images/button_selected.png")
  $(this).siblings().find("img").attr("src", "images/button_unselected.png")
});`